# Target all <a> elements with a certain textContent while no identifier is available

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, dom, properties

I have a webpage that includes some `a` tags I want to remove.

Assuming that these `a` tags have no identifier and that I also suffice them with identifiers from back end (not my site):

How could I target all these `a` elements through their `textContent` property?

I already tried these codes:

- The first brought undefined.
- The second brought unexpected identifier.

What have I missed as a JS freshman?

Code 1:

```
let textToRemove = [
"עריכה",
"עריכת קוד מקור",
"שיחה",
"גרסאות קודמות",
"מזנון",
"כיכר העיר"
];

document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach( e => {
    if ( e.textContent == textToRemove ) {
        e.style.display = "none"
    }
});
```

Code 2:

```
let strings = [
"עריכה",
"עריכת קוד מקור",
"שיחה",
"גרסאות קודמות",
"מזנון",
"כיכר העיר"
];

let links = document.querySelectorAll("a");

for ( string as strings) {
    if ( links.textContent == strings) {
        link.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of condition is this: `( e.textContent = textToRemove )`? The syntax error comes from swapped brackets `)}`, which needs to be `})` at the end of the first snippet.

Comment: @Teemu, Yeah I second you

Comment: `for ( string as strings) {...` Huh?

Comment: I confused a PHP syntax with JS ```for...in``` syntax, I think.

Comment: Fixed the typo (from `)}` to `})`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second syntax belongs to PHP.

any way, your first code have some errors, first you tried to compare array to string, instead of checking if that array contain the string.

2) the compare operator is `==` not `=`

3) You put `)` before `}` in the end of the function

Working code:

```
let textToRemove = [
"עריכה",
"עריכת קוד מקור",
"שיחה",
"גרסאות קודמות",
"מזנון",
"כיכר העיר"
];

document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach( e => {
    if (textToRemove.indexOf( e.textContent ) > -1 ) {
    e.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hf3x5zb0/

Comment: Yes, I know the comparison operator is `==` as I've written in the second example. In the first example it was a typo. Will now fix. Thank you. I will check this in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like you're trying to compare the text inside the  tags with the strings inside your `strings`/`textToRemove` array, and then hide those elements if they match up?

You have a few errors in your code. Try this instead of code1:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (strings.indexOf(x[i].textContent) != -1) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

You can't use  `==` to see if an array contains a particular string inside it. Using `indexOf` instead works because it searches for the value and returns it's index if it exists or a -1 if it does not.

Comment: Abe, `if ( strings.indexOf(links[i].textContent ) = true) {` seems a bit confusing to me. Is there another way to phrase it? I am new in JS and it really seems a bit confusing to me.

Comment: Mmm well the snippet you just commented I didn't actually write, but I can break down the 3rd line of what I posted for you. Basically I'm using the `indexOf()` method that is available for all arrays in javascript. If your array contains whatever is inside of `yourArray.indexOf(stringToLookFor)` it will return the index. If the string is not inside any of the elements of your array it will return a -1 instead. So I'm saying if the textContent of the element is inside your `strings` array, then make its display property to `none`.